# how to position a Wordpress sub-menu properly (left: auto;) not working

Tags: css

At [this site](http://www.poochesplayroom.com.au), we have a temporary sub-menu underneath Training.

Unfortunately, the sub-menu's `left: auto;` positions it to the left of the `UL`.

Other sites we use this CSS rule on position the `.sub-menu` to the left of the parent `LI`.

How can we align the `.sub-menu` of Training to be in line with the Training parent `LI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following 2 changes in your code and your sub menu will be aligned to left of parent li:

Change the following code:

```
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item:hover {
position:static;
}
```

to:

```
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item:hover {
position:relative;
}
```

and

```
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
left:auto;
}
```

to

```
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
left:0;
}
```

I hope it helps.

**Update:**

For second level menu, update the code as follows:

```
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
   left: 0;
   top: 100%;
}
.responsiveSelectFullMenu .menu-item .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu {
   margin: 0;
   left: 110px;
   top: 0;
}
.responsiveSelectFullMenu li:last-of-type .sub-menu a {
   margin-left: 0
}
```

Comment: You Da Man! Thank you Simrandeep. Can you help me with a level 2 sub-menu? Enroll > About Us > FAQ...

Comment: Yes, I can help. You can add level 2 menu on your website and I'll correct the code.

Comment: Thanks Simrandeep, done, please see `Enroll > About Us > FAQ`

Comment: Thanks. I have added the CSS. When my mouse leaves the first sub-menu to reach the second sub-menu, the second sub-menu disappears.

Comment: Okay then add one more line of code  `.responsiveSelectFullMenu .sub-menu li { display: block }`

Comment: Beaut! Thanks Simrandeep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138607/discussion-between-simrandeep-singh-and-steve).

Comment: Problem is fixed Simrandeep.